# WPF get associated label from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, label

I would like to get associated Label from code behind:

For example:

```
<Label Name="fooLabel" Target={x:Reference fooTextBox} />
<TextBox Name="fooTextBox" />
```

Pseudo Code (in Code Behind):

```
if (object.Equals(fooTextBox.AssociatedLabel, fooLabel) == true)
{
    //yeah...
}
```

(I know I could do it the other way around, `fooLabel.Target` will give me the `TextBox` but I don't have the Label, and I `think there should be a better way` than searching the `Visual Tree` for all Labels and checking their `respective Target`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Label lbl = (Label)this.FindName("fooLabel");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I am looking for. I am looking for a general solution to my problem and I don't want to write for every text box a corresponding FindName("XYZ") method. The only information I have is a random text box, and I want the associated label to this (if there is any).

Comment: @RandRandom As long as you adhere to your own naming convention (xyzTextBox -> xyzLabel), you could easily deduce the Label name from the TextBox's `Name` property.